# How to cleanly restart a WCF under new address?

Tags: c#, wpf, wcf

I have a WPF C# application hosting a WCF service. I have a routine to start the service, closing it if it already exists. WebServce is a property of type ServiceHost:

```
public void Start()
{
    try
    {

    var certificate = new X509Certificate2(certpath, "");

    String uri = "net.tcp://" + WCFAddress + "/MyService";
    Uri baseaddress = new Uri(uri);

    if (WebService != null) {
      try {
        WebService.Close();
      } catch (Exception) {
        WebService.Abort();
      }
    }

    WebService = new ServiceHost(MessageProvider, baseaddress);
    WebService.Credentials.ServiceCertificate.Certificate = certificate;
    WebService.Credentials.ClientCertificate.Authentication.CertificateValidationMode = X509CertificateValidationMode.None;

    NetTcpBinding binding = new NetTcpBinding();
    binding.Security.Mode = SecurityMode.Message;
    binding.Security.Message.ClientCredentialType = MessageCredentialType.Certificate;
    binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = TcpClientCredentialType.Certificate;
    WebService.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IMessageService), binding, baseaddress);

    WebService.Open();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        //exception handling
    }
}
```

This works fine on startup. It also works fine if I change the port number (in WCFAddress) and call the routine again. It also works if I change the address on the host computer and call it with the new IP address. However, if I change the IP address to an invalid one, the service goes into a Faulted state with the error:

> e = {"A TCP error (10049: The requested address is not valid in its context) occurred while listening on IP Endpoint=192.168.1.4:5000."}

The Close() call in the above doesn't raise an exception.

If I then change the IP address to the correct one and call again, I get the same error, with the *same* old incorrect address, even though I passed it the correct one. Also this time the Close() call raises an error due to the Faulted state, which results in the Abort() call.

I thought the Abort() call would allow the service to then be recreated? Why is it giving me an error about the old address when I'm trying to create the service with a new one? It's like it's hanging onto the old ServiceEndpoint?

Answer (score 1):

Abort(). Then just initiate a new instance with the new address.. then Open().

Comment: That's what I'm doing, right? WebService = new ServiceHost(MessageProvider, baseaddress);

Comment: as far as i know, even if you have many instances, they actually share same channels and other stuff from behind the scene.. so Abort will actually be important in this case to reset it and to allow the client to accept a new address.. just a guess..

Comment: yes, if I try Close() on a Faulted connection it raises an exception so goes to the Abort(). I have also tried testing for Faulted state and calling Abort() but it has the same problem (old endpoint raising error).